# What is Marion J. Levy's tenth Law

Tags: reference-request

I recently discovered [Marion Levy's laws](http://public.lanl.gov/cbarnes/LevyDisillusionment.html). And Princeton's news [article](http://www.princeton.edu/main/news/archive/S01/20/73Q80/index.xml) on his life claims his laws grew to eleven, but only adds the eleventh.

What is Marion J. Levy's tenth Law?

My apologies if this question does not belong here. I looked through the different Stack Exchange sites, and this one seemed to be the best fit. Please fill free to move my question to or suggest a better source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.freedominion.ca/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=505592) article quotes ten prior laws:
[(alternative source)](http://www.maths.nott.ac.uk/personal/ibf/some.html)

> 1. Large numbers of things are determined, and therefore not subject to change.
> 2. Anticipated events never live up to expectations.
> 3. That segment of the community with which one has the greatest sympathy as a liberal inevitably turns out to be one of the most narrow-minded and bigoted segments of the community.
> 4. Always pray that your opposition be wicked. In wickedness there is a strong strain toward rationality. Therefore there is always the possibility, in theory, of handling the wicked by outthinking them.
>
>    > Corollary 1: Good intentions randomize behavior.
>    >     Corollary 2: Good intentions are far more difficult to cope with than malicious intent.
>    >     Corollary 3: If good intentions are combined with stupidity, it is impossible to outthink them.
>    >     Corollary 4: Any discovery is more likely to be exploited by the wicked than applied by the virtuous.
> 5. In unanimity there is cowardice and uncritical thinking.
> 6. To have a sense of humor is to be a tragic figure.
> 7. To know thyself is the ultimate form of aggression.
> 8. No amount of genius can overcome a preoccupation with detail.
> 9. Only God can make a random selection.
> 10. Eternal boredom is the price of constant vigilance.